# C Language Command Line Arguments + Reading in File

Tags: c, linux, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to make a program which takes commands from the ubuntu terminal and reads in a file at the same time. The commands would be if the user types "-c" it will read the file and print the character count, if user types "-w" it prints the word count from the file read, "-l" to print the amount of newline characters. Anyways I attempted to do this with fscanf for the character count but it does not seem to work for some reason. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong or if there's better ways to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int i;
char words[1000];
int counter = 0;
for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
  if(strncmp(argv[i], "-c", 2) == 0){
     if(argv[i + 1] != NULL){
        while((fscanf(argv[i + 1], "[^\n]%s", words[i])) != EOF){
           counter++;
        }
     printf("%d characters\n", counter); 
     }
     printf("print character count\n");
  }
  else if(strncmp(argv[i], "-w", 2) == 0){
     printf("print word counts\n");
  }
  else if(strncmp(argv[i], "-l", 2) == 0){
     printf("print newline counts\n");
  }
  else if(strncmp(argv[i], "-h", 2) == 0){
     printf("prints help\n");
  }
}

}
```

Comment: it's `sscanf` not `fscanf` to read from a string.

Comment: You can also use getopt library to parse command line args.

Answer (score 2):

- The first parameter of `fscanf` is an open stream, not a filename.  You need to pass the filename to `fopen` to get a stream.
- The way you are trying to use `fscanf` is very insecure, as bad as `gets`, because it can easily overflow your fixed-size buffer.  `fgets`, which takes the buffer size as a parameter, would be far better.
- Your `fscanf` format string is wrong.  When you are passing a character set, the bracketed value goes after the `%` not before it, and you do not use an `s` in addition.  But this problem goes away for free when you switch to `fgets`.
- `fscanf` parameters that receive values need to be pointers, but you're passing a single array element.  Because `fscanf` is varargs, this is simply undefined behavior.  (Some compilers have special handling of `scanf` format codes and will warn you about the type mismatch, but there's no general way of detecting varargs type mismatch).
- Reading up until a newline is how you count lines, not characters.  To read single characters use `fgetc`.